# Creating an Expression<Func<T, object>> variable by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I have created the following class:

```
public class Person
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to set the following statement to a method parameter:

```
myClass.SetFieldName<Person>(p => p.LastName);
```

The type of the parameter is:

```
Expression<Func<Person, object>>
```

Now what I am trying to accomplish is to call the SetFieldName Method for a property found by reflection. Imagine I have an instance of PropertyInfo (for Person.LastName). I tried to create the Expression by using its Lambda method, but I failed.

So it would be very nice, if you can help me with this.

Regards,
Koray

Answer (score 3):

You just need to expand a little bit the flem's answer:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using NUnit.Framework;

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public static class ExpressionBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> Build<TClass, TProperty>(string fieldName)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TClass));
        var field = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, fieldName);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TClass, TProperty>>(field, param);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void TestExpressionBuilder()
    {
        var person = new Person { FirstName = "firstName", LastName = "lastName" };
        var expression = ExpressionBuilder.Build<Person, string>("FirstName");

        var firstName = expression.Compile()(person);

        Assert.That(firstName, Is.EqualTo(person.FirstName));
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the above Build() method only works for a top-level property of the TClass object. If you're trying to pass a child property expression, the PropertyOrField call fails. it does not deal with walking the object path. For example, if you had an Address object and the Person class had a property "PrimaryAddress" of type Address, you could not pass in "PrimaryAddress.PostalCode".

Answer (score 2):

```
// reflected field name
string fieldName = "LastName";

// create the parameter of the expression (Person)
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), string.Empty);

// create the expression as a get accessor of a particular 
// field of the parameter (p.LastName)
Expression field = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, fieldName);
```

Comment: Hi, I Need to pass the created Expression to the SetFieldName method as Parameter. But the Expression you created is of type Expression, which is not compatible to Expression<Func<Person, object>>.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class LambdaExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<TInput, object>> ToUntypedPropertyExpression<TInput, TOutput> (this Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> expression)
    {
        var memberName = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInput));
        var field = Expression.Property(param, memberName);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, object>>(field, param);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is how to create the `Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> expression` (that you are accepting as an argument, thus treating it as a black box) from a `PropertyInfo` found by reflection.